# Ansible: how to call module `add_host` for all hosts of the play

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm creating a playbook with this play:

On hosts `hypervisors`:

- retrieve list of virtual machines from all hosts
- use module `add_host` to add all of them in a new inventory group called `guests`

My inventory:

```
[hypervisors]
host1
host2
```

My playbook:

```
- hosts: hypervisors
  - shell: virsh list | awk 'NR>2' | awk '{print $2}'
    register: result_virsh
  - add_host:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      group: "guests"
    with_items: "{{ result_virsh.stdout_lines }}"
```

Module `add_host` [bypasses the play host loop and only runs once for all the hosts in the play](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html#notes).

Then it is called once (for host1), it's a particular case of the use of this module (see link above), as if the variable `run_once` was implicitly fixed to `true`.

How can I use it for all hosts in group `hypervisors` ?

**EDIT: Example to reproduce it on your computer with only localhost**

Create file */tmp/host1_test* to simulate a return of guests *vm1* and *vm2*:

```
vm1
vm2
```

Create file */tmp/host2_test* to simulate a return of guests *vm3* and *vm4*:

```
vm3
vm4
```

Use this inventory (*test_add_host.ini*) with two hosts, both with fixed IP address *127.0.0.1*:

```
[hypervisors]
host1 ansible_host=127.0.0.1 test_filename=/tmp/host1_test
host2 ansible_host=127.0.0.1 test_filename=/tmp/host2_test
```

Use this playbook (*test_add_host.yml*):

```
- hosts: hypervisors
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - shell: "cat {{ test_filename }}"
    register: result_virsh
  - add_host:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      group: "guests"
    with_items: "{{ result_virsh.stdout_lines }}"

- hosts: guests
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - local_action: ping
```

Call this playbook locally with command:

```
ansible-playbook -c local -i test_add_host.ini test_add_host.yml
```

- First play call hosts *host1* and *host2*
- Second play call hosts *vm1* and *vm2*

What should I do to call all hosts (*vm1*, *vm2*, *vm3* and *vm4*) in second play ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you noted, there's a thing about `add_host`: `BYPASS_HOST_LOOP = True`.
So it's a kind of forced `run_once`.

If you don't mind running over `hypervisors` in sequential manner, you can simply use `serial: 1`:

```
- hosts: hypervisors
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - shell: virsh list | awk 'NR>2' | awk '{print $2}'
      register: result_virsh
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        group: "guests"
      with_items: "{{ result_virsh.stdout_lines }}"
```

This ensures that every play batch consists of only one host, so `add_host` executes for every host.

Comment: Argh! I don't mind running `hypervisors` in serial, It was so simple in fact! THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to run the play serially you can aggregate the results with `ansible_play_hosts` and `map`. The results can be used in the next play.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - shell: virsh list | awk 'NR>2' | awk '{print $2}'
      register: result_virsh
      changed_when: false

    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        group: guests
      changed_when: false
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'result_virsh') | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | flatten }}"

- hosts: guests
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ping:
```

This answer was derived from [Ansible: Accumulate output across multiple hosts on task run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903134/ansible-accumulate-output-across-multiple-hosts-on-task-run).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem (with my localhost example) with following playbook. This solution is very complex, if you have a simpler one, shared it!

> I didn't want to use dynamic inventories

```
# Get list of virtual machines in hostvars[inventory_hostname].vms
- hosts: hypervisors
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: "cat {{ test_filename }}"
      register: result_virsh
    - set_fact:
        vms: "{{ result_virsh.stdout_lines }}"

# Remove previous vm_hosts file
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - file:
        path: /tmp/vm_hosts
        state: absent

# Build file vm_hosts with list of virtual machines in serial (working in parallele with same file cause some troubles)
- hosts: hypervisors
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - block:
        - file:
            path: /tmp/vm_hosts
            mode: 0644
            state: touch
          run_once: yes
        - lineinfile:
            dest: /tmp/vm_hosts
            line: '{{ item }}'
          with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].vms }}"
      delegate_to: localhost

# Add list of virtual machines from file vm_hosts to in-memory inventory
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - add_host:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      group: "guests"
    with_lines: cat /tmp/vm_hosts

- hosts: guests
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - local_action: ping
```