# Ansible: Accumulate output across multiple hosts on task run

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Check status of applications
      shell: somecommand
      register: result
      changed_when: False
      always_run: yes
```

After this task, I want to run a mail task that will mail the accumulated output of all the commands for the above task registered in the variable `result`. As of right now, when I try and do this, I get mailed for every single host. Is there some way to accumulate the output across multiple hosts and register that to a variable?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can extract result from `hostvars` inside a `run_once` task:

```
- hosts: mygroup
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - shell: date
      register: date_res
      changed_when: false
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'date_res') | map(attribute='stdout') | list }}"
      run_once: yes
```

This will print out a list of all `date_res.stdout` from all hosts in the current play and run this task only once.

Comment: `run_once` runs on the first host right? How does this get the variables from every host if the debug part is run on the first host not the last?

Comment: The default strategy for task execution is the [linear strategy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/linear_strategy.html#linear-strategy), each task is run on every host before moving on to the next host.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to copy the results of `date_res.stdout` to a file on host only single host data is copied not the all host's data is available

```
  - name: copy all 
    copy:
      content: "{{ allhost_out.stdout }}"
      dest: "/ngs/app/user/outputsecond-{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```