# What is the best way to check with an ansible task if my nodes are up and normal in a cluster using cassandra

Tags: cassandra, ansible

I have a cluster running cassandra 3.11.4 with 5 nodes. I'm using ansible to run tasks and I have a specific task which I only want to run if all the nodes are up and normal. I tried to use `nodetool status` and `nodetool describecluster` and check its output, but is there a better solution?

Comment: many this leads you to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903134/ansible-accumulate-output-across-multiple-hosts-on-task-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have the inventory below

```
$ cat hosts
[nodes]
192.168.50.4  node0
192.168.50.5  node1
192.168.50.6  node2
192.168.50.7  node3
192.168.50.8  node4
192.168.50.9  node5
```

The play below fails if any of the nodes do not respond at *monitor* port within *timeout* seconds. (Fit the variables to your needs.)

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    monitor: 7199
    timeout: 5
  tasks:
    - wait_for:
        port: "{{ monitor }}"
        host: "{{ item }}"
        timeout: "{{ timeout }}"
        msg: "{{ item }} is not running. End of play."
      loop: "{{ groups['nodes'] }}"
```

To check all nodes ignore potential errors, register and review results.

```
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: results
```

(not tested)